# Oracle 12c - encountering KUP-04026: field too long for datatype

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have an external table which reads from a CSV file and is failing on certain rows.

External table definition:

```
E_ID       NUMBER
A_IND      VARCHAR2 (3 Byte)
B_IND      VARCHAR2 (3 Byte)
E_DATE     DATE
E_AMT      NUMBER
F_DATE     DATE
D_E_DATE   DATE
```

I see the following info from a log file generated when I select * from the external table.

```
KUP-05004:   Warning: Intra source concurrency disabled because parallel select was not requested.

Field Definitions for table EXTERNAL_TABLE_XTL
  Record format DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
  Data in file has same endianness as the platform
  Rows with all null fields are accepted

  Fields in Data Source:

    E_ID                        CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    A_IND                     CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    B_IND                    CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    E_DATE                   CHAR (10)
      Date datatype DATE, date mask MM/DD/YYYY
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    E_AMT                    CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    F_DATE                   CHAR (10)
      Date datatype DATE, date mask MM/DD/YYYY
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    D_E_DATE               CHAR (10)
      Date datatype DATE, date mask MM/DD/YYYY
      Terminated by ","
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
KUP-04021: field formatting error for field D_E_DATE
KUP-04026: field too long for datatype
KUP-04101: record 56 rejected in file /home/TEST.csv
KUP-04021: field formatting error for field D_E_DATE
KUP-04026: field too long for datatype
KUP-04101: record 61 rejected in file /home/TEST.csv
KUP-04021: field formatting error for field D_E_DATE
KUP-04026: field too long for datatype
KUP-04101: record 70 rejected in file /home/TEST.csv
```

The file was transferred to the server via FileZilla. From reading other posts I thought maybe it was because the file was transferred in binary mode (it was originally on Auto setting) and maybe some non-printed characters have came in. So I tried to transfer using ASCII setting but that did not work. Then I tried to delete one of the lines that caused an error and retype it in manually. That did not work either.

Failed sample data:

```
5560000,N,Y,,24950,10/12/2011,10/27/2011
5550001,Y,Y,11/26/2013,73813,11/18/2013,11/29/2013
5560002,Y,Y,11/6/2015,22041.28,11/6/2015,11/18/2015
5560003,Y,Y,10/10/2012,2768.66,10/10/2012,10/24/2012
5560004,N,Y,,29750,9/30/2013,10/15/2013
5560005,Y,Y,10/8/2015,76474.84,10/8/2015,10/21/2015
5560006,N,Y,,63879.28,11/16/2011,11/30/2011
5560007,N,Y,,100000,11/14/2013,11/21/2013
```

Successful sample data:

```
5560008,Y,N,11/1/2010,,,
5550009,Y,N,,,,
5550010,N,N,,,,
5550011,N,N,,,,
5560012,Y,Y,2/12/2016,50000,2/12/2016,2/23/2016
5560013,Y,N,7/22/2011,,,
```

My first assumption is for some reason double digit months are not being accepted for the field `D_E_DATE`. Please note this is successful in the dev environment but not production and both are the same database version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was found in the following thread:
[Oracle external table date field - works in one DB and not in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982842/oracle-external-table-date-field-works-in-one-db-and-not-in-another][1])

Transferring the same file from the dev server to prod server seemed to have resolved the issue. Weird, I wish I knew better exactly why this issue occurred and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The following is working fine for me.

### Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE my_data (
E_ID       NUMBER,
A_IND      VARCHAR2 (3 Byte),
B_IND      VARCHAR2 (3 Byte),
E_DATE     DATE,
E_AMT      NUMBER,
F_DATE     DATE,
D_E_DATE   DATE
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY MY_DIR
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
  E_ID,   
A_IND,  
B_IND,
E_DATE date 'MM/DD/YYYY',
E_AMT,  
F_DATE date 'MM/DD/YYYY',
D_E_DATE date 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('data.txt')
);
```

### Sample Data:

```
[oracle@ora12c Desktop]$ cat data.txt 
5560000,N,Y,,24950,10/12/2011,10/27/2011
5550001,Y,Y,11/26/2013,73813,11/18/2013,11/29/2013
5560002,Y,Y,11/6/2015,22041.28,11/6/2015,11/18/2015
5560003,Y,Y,10/10/2012,2768.66,10/10/2012,10/24/2012
5560004,N,Y,,29750,9/30/2013,10/15/2013
5560005,Y,Y,10/8/2015,76474.84,10/8/2015,10/21/2015
5560006,N,Y,,63879.28,11/16/2011,11/30/2011
5560007,N,Y,,100000,11/14/2013,11/21/2013
```

### Output:

```
SQL> select * from my_date;

      E_ID A_I B_I E_DATE     E_AMT     F_DATE    D_E_DATE
---------- --- --- --------- ---------- --------- ---------
   5560000 N   Y             24950      12-OCT-11 27-OCT-11
   5550001 Y   Y   26-NOV-13 73813      18-NOV-13 29-NOV-13
   5560002 Y   Y   06-NOV-15 22041.28   06-NOV-15 18-NOV-15
   5560003 Y   Y   10-OCT-12 2768.66    10-OCT-12 24-OCT-12
   5560004 N   Y             29750      30-SEP-13 15-OCT-13
   5560005 Y   Y   08-OCT-15 76474.84   08-OCT-15 21-OCT-15
   5560006 N   Y             63879.28   16-NOV-11 30-NOV-11
   5560007 N   Y             100000     14-NOV-13 21-NOV-13

8 rows selected.
```